# Ajax request to php file to output mysql data

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am trying to output the row in the database which matches the forename and surname of the student from the dropdown list. i've got the function storing the first name and surname in the variable clickeditem. I must be going wrong in the Ajax/php side of things, possibly the way in which accessing the variable? When I click a name in the dropdown list nothing is occurring at all. Also I am echoing out the 'result' in the php file, how do I change that so the ajax can deal with the 'success'?  The code with html and ajax:

```
    <script 

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "out.php",             
                data: {item : item},              
                success: function(data){                    
                    $("#result").html(data); 
                    //alert(response);
                }

                });
    });
</script>
```

I have used explode to separate the first name and surname from the string as it obviously will be all in one.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: PHP needs to echo out something as whatever is echoed is returned by AJAX.

Comment: @JayBlanchard is the jquery libray not included where i wrote '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>' and it is being run on a localhost

Comment: You have included it, but if your internet connection failed you wouldn't be loading the library. It's good you're running from http://localhost, because AJAX queries require a web server as they make HTTP requests. The last thing you need to do is check for errors in the browser's console and to look at the request / response in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: @JayBlanchard im getting an internal server error in output.php

Comment: Then your PHP is failing. Check the server's error logs for more information.

Comment: Its just telling me the 500 internal error is "no store, no cache, must-revalidate" ??

Comment: Hmmmm....have you checked to make sure both variables are set ($fname, $sname)?

Comment: @JayBlanchard ya ive got them like this: $fname = $studentnospace[0];
        $sname = $studentnospace[1];

Comment: I would tell you to `print_r($result)`, but since the script is failing and we don't know where it is failing we cannot do that. Start by commenting out all of the lines, test, then add line, test, then add a line etc. until we find the line causing the failure.

Comment: For instance `$student = isset($_POST['action']);` is wrong. `$student` will be set to TRUE or FALSE as `isset()` is a *test*. If you explode `$student` it will not be what you think it is. It should be `$student = $_POST['action'];`

Comment: Ya ive just been echoing the student variable and it stops echoing when i get to the pdo and all the way down to the result variable!

Comment: @JayBlanchard ya i made an edit to the code above!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42402144/2 you didn't mark that edit as a mistake you did from your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42402144/1 and simply just overwrote it without marking it as what you also tried/changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up a test which will cause the rest of your code to fail:

```
$student = isset($_POST['clickeditem']);
```

`$student` will be either 'true' or 'false', not the string containing the first and last name. At this point your code will fail. Change the line to this:

```
$student = $_POST['clickeditem'];
```

Now `$student` is set properly and the rest of your code should work as you expect.

You also have an error in the query itself ( comma where an AND should go ):

```
WHERE student_forename=:forename, student_surname=:surname');
```

should be:

```
WHERE student_forename=:forename AND student_surname=:surname');
```

One last thing: you cannot `echo $result;` because it is an array in this section of your code:

```
if($result['count'] == 1){
    echo $result;
}
```

You must either `echo $result['count'];` or `echo $result[0];` or convert the array to another format which will be returned by your AJAX request.

Comment: still doesnt output im afraid, echoes out the answer until it gets to this line: $st->execute(array('forename' => $fname, 'surname' => $sname));

Comment: Echos out what answer?

Comment: Ive just gone along typing 'echo $sname' until it doesnt echo out anymore and that line is where it stopped

Comment: Did you make all of the changes I pointed out? Have you added `print_r($result);`?

Comment: ya made all those changes. it outputs this: Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => 1 )

Comment: Then you script is now working. You cannot `echo $result;` though, you have to `echo $result['count'];` or do something else so the result will be sent back to AJAX.

Comment: ya but im trying to output the entire row from the database based on that users name/surname, because there is other data like student email which will also need to be displayed

Comment: GAWD!!!! Really???? You should have revealed that from the start. The `print_r()` should've revealed that. Your query shows you only returning a count. You have to *help us* to *help you*.

Comment: yes sorry i'm very new to this, I realise i messed up! sorry

Comment: It's OK - all is forgiven. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's missing $ sign before fname and sname, so it should be $fname and $sname instead of fname and sname.

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    $student = isset($_POST['action']);    
    $studentnospace = explode(" ", $student);
    $fname = $studentnospace[0];// Add dollar sign before each variable
    $sname = $studentnospace[1]; // Add dollar sign before each variable
    $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=thename', 'root', 'root');
            $st = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM students WHERE student_forename=:forename, student_surname=:surname');
            $st->execute(array('forename' => $fname, 'surname' => $sname));
            $result=$st->fetch();
            if($result['count'] == 1){
                echo $result;
            }

?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Ya error on my part but still doesn't resolve the issue i'm afraid

Comment: Can you console log clickeditem and add error: on ajax, as parameter of error just console log the error param.               error: function(err){                    
                    console.log(err);
                    //alert(response);
                }

Comment: `$student = isset($_POST['action']);` that won't work.